# SequelizeEagerLoadingError and Associations

Tags: sequelize.js

I have two models which are associated to each other as follows:

```
TeamFormationMinutes.associate = (models) => {
  models.TeamFormationMinutes.belongsTo(models.Game);
}

Game.associate = (models) => {
  models.Game.hasMany(models.TeamFormationMinutes);
};
```

I want to create a query that would emulate this raw query:

```
select distinct(T.game_id) from TeamFormationMinutes T inner join Games G on T.game_id = G.id where G.competition_id=112 and G.season=2016;
```

Here is what I have done:

```
const leagueSeasonMatches = await models.TeamFormationMinutes
  .findAll({
    include: [{
      model: models.Game,
      where: {competition_id: 112, season: 2016}
    }],
    plain: true,
    distinct: 'game_id'
  });
```

But when I run it I get `SequelizeEagerLoadingError: Game is not associated to TeamFormationMinutes!` error. As far as I am concerned I defined associations between those two models. What am I missing here?

Models are like:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const TeamFormationMinutes = sequelize.define('TeamFormationMinutes', {
    team_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    team_formation_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    game_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    duration: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true
    }
  }, {
    underscored: true
  });

  TeamFormationMinutes.associate = (models) => {
    models.TeamFormationMinutes.belongsTo(models.Game);
    models.TeamFormationMinutes.belongsTo(models.Team);
    models.TeamFormationMinutes.belongsTo(models.TeamFormation);
  };

  return TeamFormationMinutes;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you reverse your `findAll`, it will work as `Game` has `hasMany` association

```
const result = await models.Game
  .findAll({
    where: {competition_id: 112, season: 2016}
    include: [{
      model: models.TeamFormationMinutes,
    }],
    plain: true,
    distinct: 'game_id'
  });
```

Do you have `foreign-key constraints` defined as part of your db schema. Should look something like this?

[image]

Comment: Still the same. This time it is `TeamFormationMinutes is not associated to Game`.

Comment: This means that the `. associate` functions are not being called. Share your model file

Comment: I added the model file for TeamFormationMinutes. The other one is organized the same.

Comment: another cause would be the wrong db settings. Updated the answer to see if you see the constraints on your db

Comment: I have it like this:

TeamFormationMinutes_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES Teams (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
---- 
TeamFormationMinutes_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (game_id) REFERENCES Games (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE